# How to fix wrong framerate without re-rendering

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine, compositing-nodes, frame-rate

I've rendered an animation in blender video editor at 13 fps, yet I accidentally rendered the composited version of the 13fps video at 10 fps, but I don't want to re-composite at 13 fps due to the fact it took so long, so what would be the method for getting the 13fps video, incorrectly rendered at 10fps during compositing, back up to 13fps? I hope that makes sense, I can barely wrap my own head around it!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134700/discussion-on-question-by-spring-how-to-fix-wrong-framerate-without-re-rendering).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed! I simply needed to re-import the video file into blender and set the fps to 13 again, making sure the base stayed at 1.00.